# How can I stop this regex from being greedy?

Tags: c#, regex

Currently this regex returns one match:

> the best language in the
> world and the fastest language

How can I get it to return two matches:

> the best language
>
> the fastest language

```
string text = "C# is the best language in the world and the fastest language in the world";
string search = @"\bthe\b.*\blanguage\b";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(text, search);
Console.WriteLine("{0} matches", matches.Count);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine("match '{0}' was found at index {1}", match.Value, match.Index);
}
Console.WriteLine("---");
```

Comment: Is this an attempt to populate SO with more Regex answers or a refusal to read documentation?

Comment: both I guess, there can never be enough different regex examples to help people understand the relationships and influences each of the parts of regex syntax can have on each other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
\bthe\b(?:(?!\bthe\b).)*\blanguage\b
```

It uses a negative lookahead assertion to require that "the" is not seen again between the matching "the" and "language".

Answer (score 5):

Add `?` after the `*`

Comment: thanks, that almost works: it gets "the best language" and "the world and the fastest language"

Comment: could you also explain why adding ? does what it does, I understand ? to mean "repeat zero or one time", would not have come upon that in solving this

Comment: @Edward `?` after `+`, `*` and `{m,n}` make them non greedy - match the smallest string possible. The second match `the world and the fastest language` is inevitable with your `.*?` - be more specific like `[^ ]*?` to match any non space character or something like that

Comment: using `[^ ]*?` returns 0 matches, but that doesn't seem the right approach since it's not the kind of characters that I want to determine (space/non-space) but the *closest* first word "the" to the second word "language", what would be a pattern for that?

Answer (score 0):

this will match your requirement

```
/the (?:best|fastest) language/g
```